# change data type column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to use Python to change the data type of each column based on the conditions and save the data type of the changed columns in a new file, so that when I take this new file to knime, it will recognize the data type of my columns. Python recognized this code, I used it, but it didn't work (it doesn't give me an error when I run the code).

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = r'C:\Users\AliReza\Desktop\Form\random_data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

def analyze_data(df):
    results = [] 
    for column in df.columns:
        int_count = 0
        float_count = 0
        string_count = 0
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            value = row[column]
            if pd.notnull(value):  
                try:
                    value = int(value)
                    int_count += 1
                    print(f'Row {index+1}, Column {column}: {value} is an integer.')
                except ValueError:
                    try:
                        value = float(value)
                        float_count += 1
                        print(f'Row {index+1}, Column {column}: {value} is a float.')
                    except ValueError:
                        string_count += 1
                        print(f'Row {index+1}, Column {column}: {value} is a string.')
        total = int_count + float_count + string_count
        if total != 0:  
            int_percentage = int_count/total*100
            float_percentage = float_count/total*100
            string_percentage = string_count/total*100
            print(f"{column} : {int_percentage}% int , {float_percentage}% float , {string_percentage}% string")
            max_percentage = max(int_percentage, float_percentage, string_percentage)
            if max_percentage == int_percentage and max_percentage == float_percentage and max_percentage == string_percentage:
                df[column] = df[column].astype(str, errors='ignore')
                results.append((column, "string", int_percentage, float_percentage, string_percentage))
            elif max_percentage == int_percentage and max_percentage == float_percentage:
                df[column] = df[column].astype(float, errors='ignore')
                results.append((column, "float", int_percentage, float_percentage, string_percentage))
            elif max_percentage == string_percentage and max_percentage == float_percentage:
                df[column] = df[column].astype(str, errors='ignore')
                results.append((column, "string", int_percentage, float_percentage, string_percentage))
            elif max_percentage == int_percentage and max_percentage == string_percentage:
                df[column] = df[column].astype(str, errors='ignore')
                results.append((column, "string", int_percentage, float_percentage, string_percentage))
            elif max_percentage == int_percentage:
                df[column] = df[column].astype(int, errors='ignore')
                results.append((column, "int", int_percentage, float_percentage, string_percentage))
            elif max_percentage == float_percentage:
                df[column] = df[column].astype(float, errors='ignore')
                results.append((column, "float", int_percentage, float_percentage, string_percentage))
            else:
                df[column] = df[column].astype(str, errors='ignore')
                results.append((column, "string", int_percentage, float_percentage, string_percentage))
        else:
            results.append((column, "No data", 0, 0, 0))  
        print(f"Column: {column}, Type: {results[-1][1]}")
        print("----------------------------------")
    df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\AliReza\Desktop\1.csv', index=False)  # تغییر نام فایل خروجی به 'a.csv'
    return df, results

df, df_results = analyze_data(df)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I used it, but it didn't work (it doesn't give me an error when I run the code)"?  If it threw an error, please post the error message, if it goves incorrect rtesults, show using a small example, whast input was processed, what output was produced and explain why the generated output is not correct/